# How can I populate the backbone model if I overrode 'fetch'?

Tags: backbone.js, google-places-api

I'm building some JS to access Google places JS API using backbone. So far I'm really stuck with the model bindings.

I overrode 'fetch' to be able to use the Google API. The call to Google works just fine.

```
var Places = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Place,

    fetch: function(options) {
        // SNIPPET //

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, this.googlePlaceCallback);

        // SNIPPET //
    },

    parse: function(response){
        // nerver  called
    },

    googlePlaceCallback: function(results, status) {
        // I do something here and is properly called after Google returns a response
    }

});
```

I also defined a very simple View:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new Places();
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.model.fetch();
    },

    render : function () {
        console.log( this.model.toJSON() );
    }

});
```

I can't figure out how to populate the 'model'. Google returns the expected results, but I can set them to the backbone model. I there something I need to do in 'googlePlaceCallback'? I'll probably will need to override 'parse' also since Google results are not quite all interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that results is a collection of the results you want, you should be able to implement the callback as follows:

```
googlePlaceCallback: function(results, status) {
    this.add(results);
}
```

Since Places is a backbone Collection, you're just calling the following method in the above code: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

You will also have to get the correct `this` reference inside the googlePlaceCallback function (you want `this` to be the Collection). One way to do that is to use Underscores `bindAll` method ( http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll ), which you can use to make sure all methods in the Backbone class have a `this` context of the Collection itself. You can do this on initialize as follows:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
}
```

Also, the reason parse is not being called is because you are overriding fetch, and fetch calls parse. If you take a look at the annotated backbone code, you will be able to see the method call: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Comment: 'This' does not seem to be the  correct context. I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'add'"

Comment: If I keep a reference to 'this' when I call 'fecth', I can use the .add method. Is it ok, to keep a reference to 'this' in that way? Seems odd to me.

Comment: code-gijoe you are correct. I have edited the answer to explain a way to maintain the correct 'this' context.